# Bind list data to a model using ajax in spring mvc

Tags: java, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I have a scenario where I want to bind data to a Model Class in spring using ajax

Model Class : EmployeeBean

```
private List<FamilyBean> familyDetails;
private String name;
//Getters and setters
```

FamilyBean Class goes here :

```
private String memberId;
private String empUserId;
private String relationship;
private String memberName;
private String age;
private String occupation;
private String contact;
private String isIncludeMedIns;
private String modefiedBy;
private String modifiedOn;
//Getters and Setters
```

JSP :

```
<input type="text" name="familyDetails[0].relationship" value="A">
<input type="text" name="familyDetails[0].memberName" value="B">
 <input type="text" name="familyDetails[0].age" value="C">
  <input type="button" value="Previous" name="_target1" id="previous">
```

Ajax Call:

```
$("#previous").click(function(){            
        $.ajax({                
            type: "POST",
            url:"saveTempEmployeeData",
            data:$("#formData").serialize(),//formData is id of the form                
            success:function (map) {                    
                //alert("SUCCESS");                                           
            },
            error:function (xhr) {
                //alert(xhr.statusText+" ERROR");
            }
        }); 
    });
```

Spring Controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/saveTempEmployeeData", method=RequestMethod.POST, headers="Accept=*")
public @ResponseBody void saveTempEmployeeData(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, @ModelAttribute("employeeBean")EmployeeBean employeeBean, ModelMap map) throws Exception{              

    userService.saveTempEmployeeData(employeeBean, pageNumber);

    try{
        System.out.println("In controller");

    }
    catch(Exception e){

    }
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
    response.getWriter().write(new Gson().toJson(map));

}
```

Data is not being binded to model attribute in the controller.

Is there any way to do it?

N.B : `<input type="text" name="name" value="Sunny">`

This data is being binded to the model.

Comment: Did you just answer your own question?

Comment: Shouldn't you use `employeeBean.familyDetails[0].relationship` in your JSP form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ModelAttribute("employeeBean")EmployeeBean employeeBean
```

This was the problem. I changed it to :

```
@ModelAttribute EmployeeBean employeeBean
```

Now everything works fine.

Thank you all for your support.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should name your input controls in JSP as shown below:

```
<input type="text" name="employeeBean.familyDetails[0].relationship" value="A">
<input type="text" name="employeeBean.familyDetails[0].memberName" value="B">
<input type="text" name="employeeBean.familyDetails[0].age" value="C">
```

That way Spring will know that it has to populate `familyDetails` inside `employeeBean`.

Comment: no. Cannot bind this way.. May be ajax can make the difference

Comment: Do you get any exception or did you try to debug the code to see what's going on? You can also log `$("#formData").serialize()` in JS console to see exactly what data is being sent to the server.

Comment: $("#formData").serialize() in alert() shows blank. @Model attribute binds nothing in controller

Comment: Okay, so that is the problem. Your form data `$("#formData").serialize()` is not getting passed to the server. At this point it has nothing to do with `@Model`. You need to check if you are referring to the correct form from your javascript.

Comment: can you copy the form definition in your jsp?